# Can I play Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt without the 'Bee nerf' update?

Tags: ps3, borderlands-2

I stopped playing *Borderlands 2* on-line after downloading and installing *Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage*; last I played my game version was still pre-"bee nerf" patch. I haven't played on-line since then as I cannot get internet on my PS3 in my dorm room. As I have the Borderlands 2 Season Pass, can I download and install (and play) *Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt* without first updating to the newest patch?

I'm only interesting in the technical possibility, not whether or not I should install the "bee-patch".

Comment: DLC often requires an up-to-date game as well, especially since Borderlands updates include DLC items, in case you're playing with a character that has them, even if you can't use them. So I doubt it's possible to get the DLC without updating, and at this point you're stuck with the latest update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends what version DLC is in the PlayStation Store.

Download the DLC, and try to play.  The PS3 should prompt you to update, if the store has an outdated version.  If you get a prompt, cancel the prompt. You're playing without the update.

Of course, you won't be able to play online, as you'll need the latest update.

Comment: If I do that (download the DLC and try to run it) and it prompts me to update,  after cancelling the prompt and disconnecting from the internet will I actually be able to play the new DLC? I guess that is my real question.

Comment: Yes, you're just choosing not to update. You could even still be connected to PSN, but you can't play online. Updated answer.